# Spring Web Flow List mapping

Tags: spring, spring-webflow

In the model bean I have a List with my objects. Like this:

```
private List<Data> data;

class Data{
      String val1;
      String val2;
...getters, setters
}
```

I need to map a few from **select** tags to a list of my objects. I mean I have something like this:

```
<select name="val1">
<option value=1>val1 value 1</option>
<option value=2>val1 value 2</option>
</select>

<select name="val2">
<option value=1>val2 value 1</option>
<option value=2>val2 value 2</option>
</select>
```

after submit action I need to have a list with one Data element with selected values (val1, val2 selects). I need a list cause I have a lot of such "select" pairs and the count is determined dynamically.
Does anybody know how to that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

if your using JSP, use `<c:forEach>`

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_foreach_tag.htm